# Loop confusion in a for loop, with a initial value of zero & it's conditions

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

In this program, I'm confused of how the for loop even executes in this `List` Class in `InsertItem()` method.

```
public class List {
    int[] a;
    int lastItem;
    public List() {
        a = new int[10];
        lastItem = -1;
    }
    public void InsertItem(int newItem, int location) {
        int i;
        for (i = lastItem; i >= location; i--) {
            a[i + 1] = a[i];
        }
        a[location] = newItem;
        lastItem++;
    }
```

My confusion: the lastItem is initialed to -1  in the for loop in InsertItem method. Say if the location is 1, how will the loop even execute if `i` is less than `0`!

I am tearing my hairs out for this problem.

Comment: What did you pass to `InsertItem(int newItem, int location)` ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained Haven't passed anything, I am just wondering how the loop works

Comment: It is not necessary for loop to work, it depends on the current value of instance variable `lastItem` and argument `location`.After adding each item, you are incrementing it by 1. `lastitem` will be initialized to -1 when you create an instance of the `List` class to access its instance method `InsertItem(int newItem, int location)`

Comment: Yes, so the first value of i is -1, then a[0] = a[0]? Omg, I am horribly confused.

Comment: If `lastItem=-1` , and `location=0`, it won't go into the loop itself , see the loop condition , `i>=location` , `-1>=0` which is not , so how do you expect the line inside the loop to be executed !!!

Comment: Exactly, so is that loop wroing is what I am saying.

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achieve!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop will execute *only* if the user enters a value less or equal to `-1` for the variable `location`.

But assigning negative values to `location` will result in an error at `a[location] = newItem;`  & `a[i + 1] = a[i];` since you will be out of boundary for the array `a[]`.

The function loop logic is broken if your goal is to fill the array with values.

I'd recommend reversing the loop to increments instead of decrements, and initializing `lastItem` to `0` so you can make this code valid with no errors.